How to determine the best number of cores and memory for Spark job
How can we determine the optimal number of cores and memory for running Spark jobs based on data volume, the number of jobs, and their frequency?
From what I've read, we can determine the number of partitions with the following formula:
No. of partitions= Data volume/Partition size (default 128 MB)

For maximum parallelism, the number of cores should match the number of partitions, but in practice, cost constraints often prevent this. Therefore, we need to determine the cycles based on the job frequency. Once we have the total number of cores based on cycles, we can calculate the number of executors:
 No. of Executors = Total cores/ Executor cores (usually recommended 2-5 cores per executor)

How do we determine the required memory? Is this approach correct? Can machine learning be used to improve this process?
